# Output node not included in the Bayesian Network

Tags: inference, bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming, pgmpy

I’m using the audio features which have a shape of (1368, 64) to do the Bayesian network structure learning with pgmpy. The actual labels for the features are added in the dataframe too. But after the learning the BN doesn’t include the output node, which makes it unable to do inference. What can I do? Can I link the output label node to the features nodes randomly or try some other methods?

I tried to change the structure learning algorithm.
I wanna know if I can link the output node to the Bayesian network nodes randomly

Comment: Just to make sure, does the output from the structure learning algorithm not have any edges to your output node? You might want to create an issue on the GitHub page here: https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy/issues with some extra info about what's going on. That way, I can help you out better.